# Iterate Multilevel Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have to iterate multidimensional array with php. My array data as following:

```
Array
(

[id] => Array
    (
        ['2'] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2
            )

        ['1'] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
            )

    )

[summary] => Array
    (
        ['2'] => Array
            (
                [0] => Summary 1
            )

        ['1'] => Array
            (
                [0] => Summary 2
            )

    )

[review] => Array
    (
        ['2'] => Array
            (
                [0] => Review 2
            )

        ['1'] => Array
            (
                [0] => Summary 2
            )

    )

[nickname] => ABCD
)
```

I want to make set of results like `array('id','summary','review', 'nickname')`

Comment: Any updates here? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$array = array(
    'id'        => array(2 => array(2), 1 => array(1)),
    'summary'   => array(2 => array('Summary ' . 1), 1 => array('Summary ' . 2)),
    'review'    => array(2 => array('Review  ' . 2), 1 => array('Review  ' . 2)),
    'nickname'  => 'ABCD'
);

$out = array();
foreach ($array as $col => $data) {
    if (is_array($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $out[$key][$col] = $value[0];
        }
    }
}

foreach ($out as &$data) {
    $data += array('nickname' => $array['nickname']);
}

var_dump($out);
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => int 2
      'summary' => string 'Summary 1' (length=9)
      'review' => string 'Review  2' (length=9)
      'nickname' => string 'ABCD' (length=4)
  1 => &
    array (size=4)
      'id' => int 1
      'summary' => string 'Summary 2' (length=9)
      'review' => string 'Review  2' (length=9)
      'nickname' => string 'ABCD' (length=4)
```